# What does code block mean in a scala anonymous function in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and don't understand what does a code block mean in anonymous function. Here is some piece of example code:

```
def makeIndex(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])] = {
    val articles_Languages = rdd.flatMap(article => {
        langs.filter(lang => article.mentionsLanguage(lang))
                                    .map(lang => (lang, article))
    })
    articles_Languages.groupByKey
}
```

Does it mean that a `WikipediaArticle` object is transformed from its original to a list of tuples `(lang,article)`,and then flatted, and by calling groupByKey it is transformed into `RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])]`?

Does it mean that I can wirte any code inside a `{}` block as long as the final line inside the block returns the object I want?In this way example code iteratored `langs` upon each article?

Comment: yes, for all your questions answer is - yes. Code block is an expression with some return value. It's used for multiple statements usually. `article => {}` - is a lambda expression, that will be converted into `Anonymous function`.

Comment: (z:Int, y:Int)=> z*y   this is an anonymous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` and `flatMap` are *high order functions*, they receive a function as a parameter and you can call them in several ways. You can just pass a method that you have defined, an anonymous function inside `()` if it has only one line, or inside `{}` if you need more lines of code.

And yes, you can pass there whatever you want if you follow the required signature, meaning that input and output have to match with the signature.

In case of `map` you have a signature `A => B` so you can transform your `A` into anything you want

Answer (score 0):

E.g. for an RDD of Int:

```
 rdd.map(x=> x+1)
```

The x => x+1 is an `anonymous` function called by `map` or some other method.

Instead of using a def with input and output definitions, the output of Int is inferred by Scala, in this case.